# AHT calculation in Power Bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, excel-2016

I am facing challenges to present the AHT (average handled time) for calls handled data in power Bi.

```
AHT = (Total Handled time)/Total calls handled.
```

Now if I have to show the `AHT` for `Q1` in Excel. We use `sumproduct` formula to calculate it.

[image]

```
formula= =SUMPRODUCT(E3:E5,F3:F5)/SUM(E3:E5)
```

However, I am not able to do it in PowerBi.

Comment: Please show your raw sample data with final output you required from them.

Comment: And, what is the unit of column AHT.

Comment: unit is time mm:ss

Comment: In excel, what is the data type of that column?

Answer (score 1):

if you can convert your Excel data as format shown in the image (just converted to **hh:mm:ss**), you can apply below steps on your data to achieve your required output-

[image]

Power query will be as below after you import excel data to power BI-

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\WORK\R&D\Book2.xlsx"), null, true),
Sheet8_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet8",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet8_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Custom", each [AHT] - DateTime.FromText("1899-12-31")),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", "Custom - Copy"),
#"Calculated Total Seconds" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Custom - Copy", Duration.TotalSeconds, type number}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Calculated Total Seconds", "Custom.1", each [calls_handled] * [#"Custom - Copy"]),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom.1", "Total Second"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns"
```

After applying above steps, you will have final data as below-

[image]

Now you can create your measure as below-

```
avg_time = SUM([Total Second])/SUM(month)
```

The returned value will be in Second. There are formula in DAX through which you will be able to conver Seconds to HH:mm:ss as per your requirement.